# Browsing left (up) in column view with no horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, window-manager

Sometimes in an "Open" or "Save" dialog you want to go one directory up. It is in column view, but there simply is no column to the left and no horizontal scroll bar. Is there a way to go up one directory without browsing completely down again from the root directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and type ".." (two dots).